# LotusRb vs Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, web-frameworks, hanami

What are the main differences between LotusRb and Ruby on Rails. At the first sight LotusRb looks very much similar to Rails. What are the pros and cons of Lotus compared to Rails?

Comment: This is a subjective question and it's not a very good fit for SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest difference is conceptual. Lotus is a modular framework aiming to a architectural style starting with the concept of a Monolith first and then extracting microservices when needed [Take a look at Lotus Overview](http://lotusrb.org/guides/architectures/overview/)

Pros: 
* Web is a option not the only way by default
* Uses concepts/patterns from DDD directly in the framework (entities, repository, adapters)

Cons:
* It's still new
* Small community and resources compared to Rails. Sometimes its hard to find real-world examples
* Rails is much more mature and battle proofed

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Lotus yet, but really want to :)

I think a big difference is that Lotus is modular and every module is an independent gem. For example if you plan use mailers you have to: `gem install lotus-mailer`

edit: I found this article quite interesting: http://teotti.com/rails-vs-lotus/